# bash command while loop only run once within Airflow kubernetespodoperator

Tags: bash, loops, airflow, kubernetespodoperator

I am trying to run one Kubernetes pod job 6 times. Each time it will print a number and sleep for 5 seconds. However, it only runs once, and then it stops. Here is the full code for the dag file:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.models import Variable
from airflow.providers.cncf.kubernetes.operators.kubernetes_pod import (
    KubernetesPodOperator,
)
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

default_args = {
    "owner": "lab",
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "start_date": days_ago(0),
    "catchup": False,
    "email": ["airflow@example.com"],
    "email_on_failure": False,
    "email_on_retry": False,
    "retries": 0,
    "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=5),
}

dag = DAG(
    "dag_executes_6_times",
    default_args=default_args,
    max_active_runs=1,
    concurrency=10,
)
# use a kube_config stored in s3 dags folder for now
kube_config_path = "/usr/local/airflow/dags/kube_config.yaml"

# Generate 2 tasks
tasks = ["task{}".format(i) for i in range(1, 3)]
example_dag_complete_node = DummyOperator(task_id="example_dag_complete", dag=dag)

org_dags = []
for task in tasks:

    bash_command = "echo HELLO"

    org_node = KubernetesPodOperator(
        namespace="default-airflow",
        image="bash",
        cmds=["bash", "-c"],
        arguments=[
            "bash",
            "-c",
            "i=0;while true;do echo '$i' && ((i++>5)) && break && sleep 5;done",
        ],
        labels={"foo": "bar"},
        image_pull_policy="Always",
        name=task,
        task_id=task,
        is_delete_operator_pod=False,
        get_logs=True,
        dag=dag,
        config_file=kube_config_path,
        in_cluster=False,
        cluster_context="lab",
    )

    org_node.set_downstream(example_dag_complete_node)
```

It will show as follows:
[image]

Basically, I want the status to be shown as running for the whole process, not just run once.
Please advise and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The loop is running 6 times, it's just not sleeping, so it finishes immediately. The problem is that in the inside of the `while` loop:

```
echo '$i' && ((i++>5)) && break && sleep 5
```

The `sleep` command is connected to the rest of the command string with `&&`, which means it'll only run if the rest of the command string succeeds `((i++>5))` and the `break` command (which actually prevents it from running anyway). You want to connect it with `;` instead, so that it runs unconditionally (although the `break` will skip it on the last iteration). Also, since `'$i'` is in single-quotes, it won't be replaced by the variable value, just printed literally; you want double-quotes. Here's what the inside of the `while` loop should look like:

```
echo "$i" && ((i++>5)) && break; sleep 5
```

(Note: you'll have to escape those double-quotes appropriately.)

Comment: Thanks Gordon for your help. I did replace the bash to be 
``` arguments=[
            "bash",
            "-c",
            "i=0; while true; do echo '\"$i'\" && ((i++>5)) && break; sleep 5; done;",
        ], ```
still it only run once.

Comment: Can you capture the output (maybe redirect it to a file, then check that) to see what it shows? If regular output doesn't show anything, add `set -x;` at the beginning (i.e. before `i=0`) and make sure you're capturing errors as well as regular output.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I'm running this job on AWS Managed Apache Airflow, and the output doesn't really show difference after setting `set -x` .
`[2022-03-29 16:09:59,770] {{logging_mixin.py:104}} INFO - [2022-03-29 16:09:59,769] {{pod_launcher.py:126}} WARNING - Pod not yet started: task1.50f9f542304043879e0623c814b5f489
[2022-03-29] {{taskinstance.py:1192}} INFO - Marking task as SUCCESS. dag_id=dag_executes_6_times, task_id=task1, 
[2022-03-29 ] {{taskinstance.py:1246}} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check`

Comment: I'm not familiar with Airflow. Can you get more info via the email options in`default_args`? If not, can you capture output on the system where the task's running, maybe bu putting something like `exec >>/tmp/task.log 2>&1; set -x;` in the command string?

Comment: I'm new to Airflow as well, still trying to sort things out. Not too sure if KubernetesPodOperator must have an image configured to load and can not directly use bash. Thank you so much Gordon.